# Alter custom field view

Tags: custom-fields

I have created a set of custom fields and I want to hide some data which have specific value, I have tried using

```
$smarty = CRM_Core_Smarty::singleton();
$smarty->assign('records', []);
```

to try and hide all the data but they are still showing.. can anyone help me?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accomplished it by filtering field data in CRM_Custom_Page_AJAX
in the function getMultiRecordFieldList(),
code goes like:

```
$data_arr = array('1','2','3');
$obj = new CRM_Profile_Page_MultipleRecordFieldsListing();
list($fields, $attributes) = $obj->browse();
foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
  if($fields[$key][[custom_field_id]]['data'] && !in_array($fields[$key][[custom_field_id]]['data'], $data_array)){
    unset($fields[$key]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer because the question is a bit too general and it depends what "hide" means. You could try something like `$form->removeElement('element_name');` in hook_civicrm_buildForm. Just for custom fields sometimes it's tricky to get the name right.